# How can I replace a word with text from earlier in the same line?

Tags: perl

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
_map[0x00000044] = "screen";
_map[0x00000059] = "map";
_map[0x0000006e] = "info";
```

I would like to replace the words at the end of each line so my output looks like this:

```
_map[0x00000044] = "0044";
_map[0x00000059] = "0059";
_map[0x0000006e] = "006e";
```

I would like to update the file in-place. I tried the following but there must be a simpler way.

```
my $infile = 'newnumbers.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";   
my @finaldata = ();

while (<$input>){
    chomp;

    print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(0x0000.*])/);
    push(@finaldata, $1);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Say the first 3 lines are what you want to edit, how do you want to change those lines?

Comment: Yes, i want my final output as _map[0x00000059] = "0059"; instead of _map[0x00000059] = "map";

Comment: do you want to edit the file itself?  or do you just want to output the results to the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = 'newnumbers.txt';

local @ARGV = ($infile);
local $^I = '.bac';
while( <> ){
    s/(_map\[0x[[:xdigit:]]{4}([[:xdigit:]]{4})\] = )".*"/$1"$2"/;
    print;
}
```

or if you're using a newer version of perl, the regex could be the following

```
s/_map\[0x[[:xdigit:]]{4}([[:xdigit:]]{4})\] = \K".*"/"$1"/;
```

Comment: getting an error "Unrecognized escape \K passed through at C:\Users\MPatel\Desktop\replacenumbers.pl line 13."

Comment: You're running an older version of perl, therefore will have to change that some.

Comment: Great help, but sorry this was just for "map" what if i want to do it for all the other lines.. such as instead of "map" there is "info" "screen" etc..

Comment: Edited to take into account you wanting to replace all words instead of just 'map'.  Also enhanced the regex to take into account hex numbers instead of just decimal.

Comment: Your hex digit range is one short (should go to `f`). I would prefer `[[:xdigit:]]` (equivalent to `[0-9A-Fa-f]`), but that's just my preference.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Updated to use the character class instead.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but can you please explain me what does this line do?  s/(_map\[0x[[:xdigit:]]{4}([[:xdigit:]]{4})\] = )".*"/$1"$2"/;

Comment: @Mihir Googling 'describe an regular expression' brings up this website: [http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl]  Then, just need to copy and paste the left side of the regex `(_map\[0x[[:xdigit:]]{4}([[:xdigit:]]{4})\] = )` for an explanation of each part.

Comment: hello Miller- i have one question, when saving back to original file using "local $^I = '.bac';" i have one minor issue. Original file has unix line endings but when saving back it adds dos line ending. How can i fix that?

Comment: You could try `use open IO => ':raw';` as documented in [`PerlIO`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO).  However, I'd recommend opening up a new question with this issue, and even refer back to this question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
my $infile = $ARGV[0] || 'newnumbers.txt';
open FH, $infile;
my @lines = <FH>;
s/(_.*(\w{4})] = ")\w+(";)/$1$2$3/ foreach @lines;
print join '', @lines;
```